# Writing nested Promises in more readable way

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

How can I write below code in a more readable way by maintaining async/concurrency flow  and result format.

```
var getUsers = () => axios.get("URL").then(res => res.data);

var getPosts = id => axios.get("URL").then(res => res.data);

var getComments = id => axios.get("URL").then(res => res.data);

Promise.map(getUsers(), user => {
return getPosts(user.id).then(posts => {
    return Promise.map(posts, post => {
        return getComments(post.id).then(comments => {
            post["comments"] = comments;
            user["posts"] = posts;
            return user;
        });
    });
});
})

.then(res => console.log(JSON.stringify(res)))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Sample Format :

```
[
{
 id:''
 name:'..',
 email:'',
 phone:''
 posts:[
        {
         postId:'...',
         title:'....'
         body:'....'
         comments: [{body:'....'},{body:'...'}]},
         {
         postId:'...',
         title:'....'
         body:'....'
         comments: [{body:'....'},{body:'...'}]
         }
        ]
  }
]
```

Each api except getUsers() below depends upon prior api for some args.
I am using bluebird promise library.
Node Js version : v9.3.0

Edited : I also tried something like but using 3 Promise.map:

```
var getPosts = id => axios.get("URL").then(res => res.data).then(posts => {
        user["posts"] = posts;
        return user;
    });

var getComments = user => {
return Promise.map(user.posts, post => {
    return axios.get(URL).then(res => res.data).then(comments => {
            post["comments"] = comments;
            return user;
        }).then(users => users[0]);

getUsers()
.then(users => Promise.map(users, getPosts))
.then(users => Promise.map(users, getComments))
.then(res => console.log(JSON.stringify(res)))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: Nesting gives closures. Closures are highly beneficial here. Suggest you stick with what you have. It's not particularly unreadable.

Comment: `user.posts = posts` can be moved out one level.

Answer (score 0):

To make more readable your code and prevent that ugly `Promise hell` your should use the `async/await` syntax.

```
async function foo() {
    async function getUsers() {
        var res = await axios.get("URL")
        return res.data
    }

    async function getPosts(id) {
        var res = await axios.get("URL")
        return res.data
    }

    async function getComments(id) {
        var res = await axios.get("URL")
        return res.data
    }

    var users = await getUsers()
    for (var user of users) {
        var posts = await getPosts(user.id)
        for (var p of posts) {
            var comments = await getComments(p.id)
            p['comments'] = comments
        }
        user['posts'] = posts
    }
    return users 
}
```

And then you use that like this

```
foo()
.then(users => console.log(users))
.catch(e => console.log('Whatever throw or reject inside foo', e))
```

If it was me I would do something like this

```
async function foo() {
    var users = await axios.get("users URL")
    for (var user of users.data) {
        var posts = await axios.get("post URL" + user.id)
        for (var p of posts.data) {
            var comments = await axios.get("comments URL" + p.id)
            p['comments'] = comments.data
        }
        user['posts'] = posts.data
    }
    return users.data
}
```

Comment: OP did explicitly ask for "*maintaining async/concurrency flow*".

Comment: He said **more readable way by maintaining async/concurrency**, so that promise hell is whatever but nothing to do with efficiency at the maintenance time

Comment: @FernandoCarvajal thanks for response but bergi is right

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say it's particularly unreadable. Looping requires nesting. One minor improvement might be using the [prototype `.map` method](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/map.html) instead of `Promise.map`:

```
getUsers().map(user =>
    getPosts(user.id).map(post => {
        getComments(post.id).then(…)
    )
).then(res =>
    console.log(JSON.stringify(res))
).catch(err =>
    console.error(err)
);
```

---

However, there seems to be a grave mistake in your code. You are mapping posts to users, which would lead to repetitions of a user for every post he made, and omitting users that made no posts entirely. That's probably not what you want. Instead, return the user after having fetched his posts and comments.

```
getUsers().map(user =>
    getPosts(user.id).map(post => {
        getComments(post.id).then(comments => {
            post["comments"] = comments;
            return post;
        })
    ).then(posts => {
        user["posts"] = posts;
        return user;
    })
).then(users => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(users));
}).catch(console.error);
```

Alternatively we could keep the array whose contents we are mutating anyway, though we'd need to use `then` instead of `map` if we want access to the array.

```
getUsers().then(users =>
    Promise.map(users, user =>
        getPosts(user.id).then(posts => {
            user.posts = posts;
            return Promise.map(posts, post =>
                getComments(post.id).then(comments => {
                    post["comments"] = comments;
                })
            );
        })
    ).then(() =>
        console.log(JSON.stringify(users))
    )
).catch(console.error);
```